# Underbracket text with label within bracket?

Tags: labels

I'm looking to do something like this:

[image]

with the `underbracket` operator, where the label text is inline with the bracket. Is there an easier way rather than fiddling with that operator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `tikzmark` for this:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\begin{document}

\huge
\tikzmark{firststart}john\tikzmark{firstend}.\tikzmark{laststart}doe\tikzmark{lastend}@\tikzmark{domainstart}example.com\tikzmark{domainend}

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture,marking/.style={font=\scriptsize\scshape,fill=white,inner sep=1pt}]
  \foreach \part in {first,last,domain}
  \draw ([yshift=-5pt]pic cs:\part start) -- ++(0,-5pt) -- node[marking,midway]{\part} ([yshift=-10pt]pic cs:\part end) -- ++(0,5pt);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]